# Using QGIS to create road map layered on top of a topography map

Tags: qgis

Forgive me for my lack of knowledge on GIS. I have only very recently come across this subject, and I believe that I can arrive at what I'm looking for using QGIS and OSM data. I'm a bit lost with all the available information.

I want to create an map where I can layer different levels of road infrastructures (motorways, primary, secondary) on top of a topography map. I'm doing this because I enjoy motorcycle touring and am trying to plan trips through twisty mountain roads. If at all possible, I'd also like to be able to overlay this information on Google Earth Pro, so that I get the street-view option. I'm looking for European roads, particularly for Portugal and Spain.

Am I asking for too much? And if not, could you give me some pointers as to what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

For an Example in QGIS (Portugal)
[image]

1.Download from http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/portugal.html
(portugal-latest-free.shp.zip shapefiles zipped)

2.Load into QGIS (drag & drop)

[image]

3. Categorize the data and Style as you want.

[image]

4. Export to KML (Extent - you might need to export to reduce the data/attributes.)
5. Open in Google Earth (can be slow if KML is large)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was missing the "Categorizing" step, which meant that I couldn't filter for types of road.